# Necessary references when using class that is derived

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working with a simple daemon that accesses a mysql database using entity framework.
The solution contains two projects:

- Test.Daemon
- Test.DataAccess

`Test.DataAccess` will contain all classes used for code-first and also contains a class `TestDbContext` which is derived from `DbContext`

- EntityFramework 5 is installed via NuGet for `Test.DataAccess`
- `Test.DataAccess` is referenced in `Test.Daemon`

Now when I try to use the following in `Test.Daemon` it complains about the missing reference to EF:

```
TestDbContext ctx = new TestDbContext();
```

**Resulting Error:**
*The type 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'*

As soon as I reference EF in `Test.Daemon` the code works without issues.

Why is it not sufficient to reference the project that contains the derived class and itself has references to the class it derives from?

Comment: Why? Because it's not designed that way.

Comment: So you are telling me there is no way around that in my specific scenario?

Comment: Why do you need a "way around" it?  Just add the proper references.

Comment: This is not a problem; it is a requirement. You have to reference Entity Framework in any executable that uses your Entity Data Model.  Just the way it was designed.

Comment: Well my intention was to keep the overall project as clean as possible and my understanding was that it should be enough to reference the derived class if the derived class itself references its parent. This is obviously not the case - thanks for clarifying.
Kirk you should add this as briefly elaborated answer so I can mark it as solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it not sufficient to reference the project that contains the derived class and itself has references to the class it derives from?

I think you are confusing some concepts here.  Assemblies don't derive from other assemblies, they *reference* them.  This means that to use an assembly, you have to have a copy of all the assemblies it references, and so on down the chain.  Why aren't they automatically packaged up together?  Because if I have my program which uses assemblies x, y, and z,  and those assemblies had all packaged up a single common assembly, that means I would have *three copies* of that common assembly in my program.  But because of referencing, only one copy of the assembly is utilized by all three.

Now, why doesn't Visual Studio automatically add the further assemblies that you are dependent on for you?  Well, I fibbed.  You don't actually need any assembly unless you are actually exercising code that exists in it.  So if I reference assembly x, and I use only a portion of assembly x that isn't dependent on assembly y, I don't need assembly y.